# Trouble with running R shiny app - staticPath error

Tags: r, shiny

I used to have no trouble running apps on my local machine; now, whenever I click the Run App button, I get an error saying:

"Error in staticPath(path) : 'path' must be a non-empty string."

It gets as far as "Listening on http://....", and then the staticPath error pops up. Sometimes this goes away after I restart my session a number of times, but its been persistent and frustrating!!

Any idea what on earth this might be caused by and how I can fix it? I have tried creating even the most simple, do-nothing app, and it still happens, so I do not think the issue is in my actual code...

It even happens with this sample code:

```
library(shiny)


# app
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  
  # classic app
  headerPanel('Iris k-means clustering'),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris)),
    selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', names(iris),
                selected=names(iris)[[2]]),
    numericInput('clusters', 'Cluster count', 3,
                 min = 1, max = 9)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput('plot1')
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # classic app
  selectedData <- reactive({
    
    req(auth$result)  # <---- dependency on authentication result
    
    iris[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol)]
  })
  
  clusters <- reactive({
    kmeans(selectedData(), input$clusters)
  })
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    palette(c("#E41A1C", "#377EB8", "#4DAF4A", "#984EA3",
              "#FF7F00", "#FFFF33", "#A65628", "#F781BF", "#999999"))
    
    par(mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 0, 1))
    plot(selectedData(),
         col = clusters()$cluster,
         pch = 20, cex = 3)
    points(clusters()$centers, pch = 4, cex = 4, lwd = 4)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

and here is the error i get, word for word:

```
> library(shiny); runApp('app_AuthenticationPage.R')

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7948
Error in staticPath(path) : `path` must be a non-empty string.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, nomathewise! You'll need to make this question reproducible, including a sample (small) shiny app that produces the error in your RStudio instance. Please take a quick look at some methods for providing a self-contained reproducible question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info. Thank you!

Comment: Is this a full reproducible example?

After removing `req(auth$result)` from your code the app runs on my machine. Ok, it crashes when selecting "species" as x or y variable but that seems not to be your problem.

Comment: Hi! So sorry about the ```req(auth$result)``` bit -- I had been using that piece of code to test out authentication modules and must have missed deleting that last part when i posted it here... 
And you're right, that isn't quite my problem - the app itself is irrelevant, the problem comes from even just trying to run it - it never gets to opening! 

But thank you for replying!!!!!